# React Native and i18n-js: Add component in translated string

Tags: javascript, react-native, internationalization

I'm using [`i18n-js`](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js), as recommended by [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/localization/). Let's say I want a screen with a `<Text>` that looks like:

```
<Text>Click on <Text style={bold}>this link</Text> now.</Text>
```

Here's what I would do:

```
const en = {
  click_link: "Click on {{link}} now.",
  link: "this link"
};

<Text>
  {i18n.t('click_link, {
    link: <Text style={bold}>{i18n.t('link')}</Text>
  })}
</Text>
```

But it does'nt work, it shows `<Text>Click on [object Object] now.</Text>`

So the only idea I have now is:

```
const en = {
  click_link_1: "Click on",
  click_link_2: "this link"
  click_link_3: "now."
}

<Text>
  {i18n.t('click_link_1')}
  <Text style={bold}>{i18n.t('click_link_2')}</Text>
  {i18n.t('click_link_3')}
</Text>
```

But it seems not elegant at all.